# Drupal 7 Megamenu Construction Using Views in Menu and a menu module?

Tags: 7, routes, navigation

Currently I need to construct a responsive Megamenu and so far I have narrowed down that I need **menu_views** (https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_views) to output the megamenu items as each dropdown will contain a bunch of recent nodes relating to the sub menu items.

I've been using **responsive_menu** for my menu, but apparently its not compatible with **menu_views** as it doesnt output the views in the menu.

It's either I code this responsive menu from scratch, but I rather not if there is a solution for this already that can get me more than 50% of the way there.

Now my question is,  what menu modules would make it compatible with "menu_views"? Or maybe another solution all together. I know about tb_megamenu, but that module seems to have alot of bloat with bootstrap built right into it.

Comment: FYI: i tried nice_menus thinking it was better due to the fact it was more upto date, but I ended up with just going with superfish as that seems to be the most robust for building out megamenus combined with menu_views module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try the [Superfish module](https://www.drupal.org/project/superfish). The Menu Views module page states it should be compatible with the current stable release of Superfish.

Superfish is also responsive out-of-the-box (based on user agent or window width).